# How to get a line after Key_Return press in QTextEdit

Tags: qt

I get characters in my QTextEdit. After pressing an Enter key I want to get the line before the key and parse it.

```
static QString term_str;

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (obj == ui->textEditTerminalTx)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
        {
            QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
            if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Return)
            {
                //term_str += '\r';
               QByteArray ba = term_str.toLocal8Bit();
               char *str  = ba.data();

               compars.ParseCommand(str);

               term_str.clear();
            }
            else
            {
                if (keyEvent->key() != Qt::Key_Backspace && keyEvent->key() != Qt::Key_Delete)
                    term_str += static_cast<char> (keyEvent->key());

                return false;
            }
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
        return MainWindow::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

And I get but in upper case.
If I type - **test** - in textEditTerminalTx and in term_str I see **TEST** 
Why the function is ignoring the CapsLock key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the character pressed then you must use the `text()` method instead of using `key()` since the latter does not have the information to differentiate between upper and lower case.

```
// ...
if (keyEvent->key() != Qt::Key_Backspace && keyEvent->key() != Qt::Key_Delete)
    term_str += keyEvent->text();
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you. It works good. Now I'd like to get my method more sophisticated.  I type - **mycommand param1 param2** - and pass it to the parser. Now I go with Backspase key to, say  **mycommand param1** and press Enter - but I already invoked - term_str.clear(); - so I pass an empty string. On the other hand I don't want the string to gather old commands.

Comment: @john7 Mmm, that's another problem, so you should post a new question as the SO rules point out.